# How to get cumulative values and reset it under a condition, and then aggregate it again on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the column `cumulative_point` like below.

| date | point | reset_date | cumulative_point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | true | 1 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 3 | false | 4 |
| 2019-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | false | 5 |
| 2019-01-04 00:00:00 | 2 | false | 7 |
| 2019-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 | true | 1 |
| 2019-01-06 00:00:00 | 4 | false | 5 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 | 2 | false | 7 |

`cumulative_point` is a cumulative value of `point` column, then reset it when `reset_date` column is `true` and doesn't take over the previous cumulative value.

I have been trying to do this for a while but I couldn't figure out how to reset `cumulative_point` when the `reset_date` column is `true`.

I did like

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN reset_date then 0 ELSE point END) as cumulative_point
```

but then the `SUM` function added values to the previous value like below.

| date | point | reset_date | cumulative_point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | true | 1 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 3 | false | 4 |
| 2019-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | false | 5 |
| 2019-01-04 00:00:00 | 2 | false | 7 |
| 2019-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 | true | 1 |
| 2019-01-06 00:00:00 | 4 | false | 12 |
| 2019-01-07 00:00:00 | 2 | false | 14 |

How can I reset the cumulative values by sum() when `reset_date` is true and ignore the previous cumulative values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the running sum of 'reset_date' (1 where true, 0 where false) to define a new group whenever a true value is shown, then use the cumulative sum of 'point' partitioned by that group.

```
Select date, point, reset_date,
  SUM(point) Over (Partition By grp Order By date) As cumulative_point
From
(
  Select *, 
   SUM(Case When reset_date Then 1 Else 0 End) Over (Order By date) As grp
  From table_name
) T
Order By date
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LgHSpiqO).

Answer (score 0):

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5NAuticA)

create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW test1 AS
SELECT
    *
    , CASE WHEN reset_date THEN
        0
    ELSE
        point
    END AS reset_point
    , lead((
        CASE WHEN reset_date THEN
            0
        ELSE
            point
        END) , 1 , 0) OVER (ORDER BY date)
    , lag((
        CASE WHEN reset_date THEN
            0
        ELSE
            point
        END) , 1 , 0) OVER (ORDER BY date)
FROM
    cumulative_point
ORDER BY
    date;
```

query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN lead > 0
            AND lag > 0
            AND reset_point = 0 THEN
            1 --sequence false true false.
        WHEN lead = 0
            AND lag > 0
            AND reset_point = 0 THEN
            1 --- sequence false true true.
        WHEN lead > 0
            AND lag = 0
            AND reset_point = 0 THEN
            1 --- sequence true true false
        WHEN lead = 0
            AND lag = 0
            AND reset_point = 0 THEN
            1 -- true true true
        END AS grp
    FROM
        pg_temp.test1
),
cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        count(grp) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS real_grp
FROM
    cte
)
SELECT
    date,
    point,
    reset_point,
    reset_date,
    reset_point,
    sum(reset_point) OVER (PARTITION BY cte1.real_grp ORDER BY date)
FROM
    cte1;
```

basic idea is `reset_date` is boolean. I added more test case. Hope covered  all the corner case. using window function can solve the problem.